# NanoHTTPD how to present variable from app

Tags: java, dynamic, html, nanohttpd

I play NanoHTTPD and WebServer based on it. To update any object in my code (application) I can use GET/POST method. But how can I create dynamic pages? For example I have html page on disc and it should present current temperature:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p style="text-align: center">Temperature: [temperature variable] </p>

  </body>

</html>
```

How can I pass "variable temperature" from my application based on NanoHTTPD to html file and present it in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the template from your disk, and replace the `[temperature variable]` substring with the value you want to include.

To read the file, you can use the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mytemplpate.html"));
String templ = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

To insert your temperature:

```
double temperature = 22.3;
String html = templ.replace("[temperature variable]", Double.toString(temperature));
```

And finally to send this as the response with NanoHTTPD:

```
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(html);
```

**The complete program:**

*Foreword: Exceptions are not handled, this is just for demonstration purposes.*

```
public class TemperatureServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    // Loaded and cached html template
    private static String templ;

    // Value of this variable will be included and sent in the response
    private static double temperature;

    public TemperatureServer () {
        super(8080);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String html = templ.replace("[temperature variable]",
            Double.toString(temperature));
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(html);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("mytemplpate.html"));
        templ = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        ServerRunner.run(TemperatureServer.class);
    }
}
```

For more advanced examples check out the [Samples package](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen) of the NanoHttpd Github site.